# Nuxt 3 import lodash globally for entire app

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to figure out what is a right way to import lodash globally for the application rather inside each setup tag.

I have tried to set up lodash as a plugin

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'
import _ from 'lodash'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  return {
    provide: {
      _: () => _
    }
  }
})
```

Above doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you have provided it as a function and have to call it as a function like:

```
{{ $_().join(["a", "b", "c"], "~") }}
```

and the plugin you want:

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from "#app";
import lodash from "lodash";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  return {
    provide: {
      _: lodash
    }
  };
});
```

and then in the template:

```
{{ $_.join(["a", "b", "c"], "~") }}
```

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hello-lodash-plugin-5gg59)